# How to use attention to weigh the sum of two tensors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, classification, attention-model

I have a working neural network with two data streams as a backbone network. Now I'm working on the classification head and would like to sum the features extracted from the two streams in the backbone using an attention mechanism, but unfortunately I didn't understand how I could do it. Using pytorch, I have this code:

```
def forward(self, x):

    x1, x2 = self.pooling_layer(x[0]), self.pooling_layer(x[1])

    assert x1.shape == x2.shape, 'The dimension of the rgb features and the pose features should be the same'

    x1 = x1.view(x1.size(0), -1)
    x2 = x2.view(x2.size(0), -1)

    x = # Perform sum with attention

    assert x.shape[1] == self.in_channels

    if self.dropout_layer is not None:
        x = self.dropout_layer(x)

    scores = self.fc_layer(x)
    return scores
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can implement this?

Comment: What is the shape of `x1`?

Comment: In this case, the size of x1 and x2 are the same [Bx256x32x232x232] where B is the batch size, but I would like to understand how to do it in general

Comment: Since you asked about the general idea - here goes: it depends on the task you are trying to solve and what those tensors represent usually. Usually these two give you an indication of what you need to do.

Comment: I have two streams and I want to fuse the features, what I'm missing is the understanding of how to implement the sum of the features weighted with the attention, which I would like to make sure the network learns which of the two feature extraction branches carries the most information using this mechanism